# Failed to run autopoint: No such file or directory

Tags: python, android, linux, github-actions, dlib

I have made a python project using **python** and **kivy** and using **github actions** to build an android app since buildozer runs on linux.

**Dlib** is one of the requirements for the app. I am not well versed in these compiling tools but I guess buildozer is implicitly using these tools to compile dlib.

When I push changes to my repository, after sometime the build is failing with this error :

```
  RAN: /usr/bin/autoreconf -vif
  STDOUT:
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: running: autopoint --force
Can't exec "autopoint": No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 345.
autoreconf: failed to run autopoint: No such file or directory
autoreconf: autopoint is needed because this package uses Gettext
```

But when i try to install autopoint, it is showing as already installed. I have even tried to install aclocal, make, autoconf, autoreconf manually but still no improvement.

**Path to autopoint :**

```
autopoint: /usr/bin/autopoint /usr/share/man/man1/autopoint.1.gz
```

**Path to autoconf :**

```
autoconf: /usr/bin/autoconf /usr/share/autoconf /usr/share/man/man1/autoconf.1.gz
```

**Path Variable :**

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/runner/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/runner/.cargo/bin:/home/runner/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/runner/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

These are some extra dependencies I've installed :

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip build-essential git python3 python3-dev ffmpeg libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev zlib1g-dev
```

```
sudo apt-get install -y libgstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```

```
sudo apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev
```

Is there an issue with autopoint installation or am i doing something else wrong? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the error in Fedora Linux by installing the gettext-devel package.

For Ubuntu, I wasn't able to isolate the equivalent package but I searched "gettext" in Ubuntu Packages and installed a few until the error resolved.